# How to load a large amount of Google Web Fonts?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

Is there a better way to load a large amount of Google Web Fonts into a single page?

Maybe delay loading certain ones while the page loads? Or maybe only load certain fonts after the user scrolls down to a specific point?

I can't help but think there is a better way of loading several fonts. After putting 2 or 3 in the Google "Font Collection" the page load is apparently pretty high.

I am not trying to be tacky by designing with a bunch of fonts, but I am trying to think of a better way to display a lot of fonts — kind of like a specimen book.

I guesss the best example would be the infinite scroll on [Myfonts](http://new.myfonts.com/search/sans++serif/). I know that those fonts aren't displayed using web fonts, but I think there should be a similar way of loading web fonts. I mean, how does google load all of those fonts on the [homepage](http://www.google.com/webfonts)?

Comment: I was thinking that the first fonts visible above the page fold would load first, and then the ones not seen further down the page would load later.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below. See if it is what you wanted. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to work out for you, but Google Web Fonts does provide a JavaScript method, which you can set when to use the font. (Maybe load the fonts after the page done loading?)

Try the live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bkV7E/).

Example (Using font [*Glass Antiqua*](http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3a)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Glass+Antiqua::latin' ] }
  };
  var YOURFUNCTION = function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  };

  //Maybe 10 seconds later?
  setTimeout(YOURFUNCTION, 10000);

  //Document Ready?
  $("body").ready(YOURFUNCTION);
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bkV7E/

Comment: Great! So right now you have it set up as a timed delay. How would it work if I wanted to display the fonts once they were fully loaded?

Comment: @davecave, it will use the font automatically when it finishes loading.